# How to make Jenkins source code checkout conditional?

Tags: git, jenkins, ant

I have a Jenkins project that has a number of potential subprojects that it can build, each in its own Git repository. It's already set up such that any subset of the projects can be specified to build, which is what we want. i.e. we specify a comma separated list of plugins, say p1,p3,p7 and they represent a subset of the full list of available projects/repos. They are the bundled together into the final build and delivered as a single unit.

However, by default, Jenkins checks out each of these project's repositories every time, regardless of whether we're building it or not. Is there a way -- whether it be out of the box or a plugin -- to prevent Jenkins from checking out the repositories we aren't using?

We need to maintain the ability to build/send them together, so simply breaking them up into separate projects isn't really appropriate for our needs, and one of the subprojects is particularly large, doesn't change often, and eats up a lot of build time, so the status quo isn't satisfactory. I basically need

```
if projectSpecified then checkout project
```

to be the behavior. I've looked a bit at the Run Condition Plugin and it appears to apply only to actually build steps and not SCM.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have a project in which we're doing conditional checkout, but it's a [Workflow-based](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin) project. You can make pretty much any behavior conditional, but you may have to refactor your job significantly assuming it is not already a Workflow project.